# How to change a docker repository to automated build?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Is it possible to change a *repository* (https://hub.docker.com/r/hrasoa/webdev/) to an *automated build* ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did previously and what you want to automate?

Answer (score 0):

It is already an automated build.

Log of latest build: https://hub.docker.com/r/hrasoa/webdev/builds/byeg2f8shx8qhl2ay2zj5ta/